# Pushing view controller from popover controller

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a Popover which I present from a bar button over a navigation controller. This popover will act as a menu. When a row is pressed I want to push a new view controller on the navigation stack.

How do I communicate between the two classes though? The table in the popover is controlled via a UITableViewController subclass and the class that presents the popover is a view controller on the navigation stack.

Any ideas, I'm really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter`. Just add an observer in the main view somewhere (probably in the `viewDidLoad` method. Then when the row is tapped in the `UIPopoverController` post the notification. [Here's](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html) a guide to help you out.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. That's the first time I've worked with NSNotificationCenter so wouldn't have known to use it without your help.